# Is it possible to create unary operators in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, operators

I want to create a unary operator that runs this method:

```
def @*
    self **= 2
end
```

I have a project where squaring is important, and I don't want to write '**=2' every single time. I have searched extensively, and yet have not found an answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What would you have called instead of `**` ?

Comment: Although such method doesn't exist, it would be `*@`, not `@*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't work. Ruby supports unary [methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html), but only `+`, `-`, `~` and `!`.

Besides, although you can write a method that will square a number:

```
class Numeric
  def square
    self ** 2
  end
end

3.square #=> 9
```

you can't write a method that will modify a number – numbers are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question stated:

> I have a project where squaring is important, and I don't want to write `**=2` every single time.

Sacrifice `Integer#~`:

```
class Integer
  def ~@
    self ** 2
  end
end
```

While you are still unable to mutate the `Numeric` instance, you are now able to use it in calculations:

```
5 + ~4
#⇒ 21
```

Comment: You are suggesting to replace the built-in [`Integer#~@`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Integer.html#method-i-7E)?

Comment: @Stefan yes I am. I understand the circumstances and I would never do this in my own project since I have no problems with `i **= 2` notation. Basically that’s why I used a word “sacrifice.”

Comment: I think one should also emphasize, that this kind of sacrifice could be suicidal, because if the application also uses some classes from the Ruby standard library, or some Gems, or third party library, and the monkey-patch for `Integer` is seen by Ruby earlier than the *require* of that library, it will lead to unpredictable results.

Comment: A nice example why one should never do this, is the mathn library, which changes the meaning of core `Integer` methods and completely broke Rubinius, because in Rubinius the entire core library, the kernel, the low-level data structures, and the compiler are all written in Ruby, and all rely on `Integer` working as documented, so when you `require 'mathn'`, the entire system just crashes. This has been fixed, by inserting a "monkey-patch safe layer" underneath normal Ruby that Rubinius internals use, but that is an ugly hack.